# Internet connection not working in physical device - android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, internet-connection

Before my app internet connection was working fine in physical device but suddenly it stopped taking data from the firebase and I can't see any error in the logcat or any other thing. After searching a lot I didn't got anything, any help would be appreciable.

> I have applied all the required permission in the manifest file.
> all dependencies are up to data and working fine.
> Restarted the android studio.
> Rebuild and clean project are also checked but no help

thanks in advance

Comment: You say "Internet connection". So in that case, how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: I got it now like I have to change the rules of the firebase database